# Complete summary of all protection in a circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, short-circuit, circuit-protection, over-voltage-protection

this is what I have learned and I wanted to know if you can add more to my current understanding in protection.

- For short circuit (which applies both to overvoltage and overcurrent): Use a fuse first and then a tvs diode.
- For reverse protection: a diode will suffice

Is there any other protection that can be added to a circuitry?
This is a general question.

Comment: You're asking only about fault protection, not ESD protection and EMC, right? The answer really depends on *what you need to protect* versus *what you need to protect against*. The kind of fault protection needed on a hobbyist breadboard is different than the fault protection needed in an industrial factory automation setting or in a medical device or a radar system. There are tradeoffs involving cost, size, signal distortion, etc.  Henry W. Ott wrote many, many papers on the subject of EMC (Electromagnetic Compliance) and circuit protection, it's a very broad and deep subject.

Comment: The hacker in me wants to simply answer "Yes" (because there is other protection circuitry that can be added...) but it really is dependent on the "attack profile" of what kind of faults you anticipate needing to protect against. So it's hard to give a meaningful general answer without becoming a whole college-level seminar.

Comment: @MarkU. Got it. Thanks I will close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For short circuit (which applies both to overvoltage and overcurrent):
> Use a fuse first and then a tvs diode.

TVS diode always comes first, than the fuse.

If you do the opposite way, your fuse might blow because the TVS will shunt to ground the current of all over voltage events.

Yet, the fuse might not stand over voltage transients.

[image: Protection]

Comment: This sort of contradicts what you are saying: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/507218/difference-between-placing-unidirectional-tvs-diode-before-fuse-or-after-p-mosfe

Comment: Check that link. I didn't answer that question. TVS comes first than the fuse.

Comment: In the link, it says that the fuse should comes first before tvs diode. That's all

Comment: Read my answer. If you put the FUSE first, you'll blow it during EFT EMI tests, because the TVS will shunt to ground all the current of the over voltage fast transient event.

Comment: I understand. Thanks

Comment: Curious about what happens if the Tvs diode does short; would the power supply that is supplying the power burn? Since the tvs diode has shorted, do you think the fuse will even be needed since all the power will be going through the tvs diode.

Comment: MTBF of TVS diode PESD1CAN by NEXPERIA is 1.92E+09 hours which means more than 200 years. Source: https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/quality-document/PESD1CAN_Nexperia_Product_Quality.pdf

Comment: Just wanted to know if the fuse is even required when tvs diode handle both the overvoltage and over current. Logically when there is an overvoltage, there is an overcurrent as well. Would like to hear your thought on this.

Comment: TVS handles over voltage only. I don't use fuses that often because power supplies are output current limited. I use fuses only when the power supply is supposed to supply in parallel more than one board/product, that is shared.